# How to get text of a value in elements which doesn't contain text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

From the following tag

```html
<div class="ms-TextField-fieldGroup fieldGroup-387"><input type="text" id="TextField137" name="admin.email" aria-labelledby="TextFieldLabel139" class="ms-TextField-field field-388" aria-invalid="false" value="automail190622161335@yopmail.com"></div>
```

I need to get the text of Value from the above element i.e "automail190622161335@gmail.com". If the element contains the text we can use .text but here there is no text. So can someone help related to this?

Answer (score 0):

use `.innerHTML` or `.value`, depending on the element.